# Host an ASP.Net service in Windows Services instead of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Im trying to host my ASP.Net development in a Windows Service instead of in IIS.

Is this possible?

So far I have not had much look finding anything on google.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: what do you mean ASP.Net service? If WCF, yes you can, but web site, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can host parts of ASP.NET outside IIS, like WCF services. But if you want to host all ASP.NET you will have to proivde many features which are build in in IIS.

But you do not have to use IIS, You can try also:

- [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview),
- [apache with mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)
- [cassini](https://code.google.com/p/cassini/)